# Getting ReflectionTypeLoadException on 2nd attempt at reflection in .net 4

Tags: c#, .net, exception, reflection, .net-4.0

In my project I have the following helper method, which goes through all the assembly and gets all types that are subclasses of the BaseCamaFrom type.

```
    public static List<Type> GetAllTestActionFormTypes()
    {
        List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

        // add all the types that are subclasses of BaseCamaForm to the _camaFormType list
        foreach (Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
            foreach (Type t in asm.GetTypes())
                if (t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseCamaForm)))
                    types.Add(t);

        return types;
    }
```

This method works correctly on the first call.  However, upon calling this method a second time the following exception occurs when the `asm.GetTypes()` is called:

```
ReflectionTypeLoadException was unhandled by user code: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
```

Upon looking at the LoaderException property I found a `System.IO.FileLoadException` with the following message:

```
Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.
```

Why does this code work the first time it is called but always exceptions the second time?

---

**Edit:** After more investigation, the only assemblies I reference that have a Runtime Version of 2.0.50727 are Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client. I cannot figure out why these references are causing issues with reflection, nor why it seems to happen only on the 2nd attempt. This seems to sporadically also occur as well when attempting to use the `Activator.CreateInstance(types[x])` call on some classes.

Comment: Can you clarify when "first" vs "second" calls occur? If you call it twice explicitly in a row, that would indicate one problem, while twice with a bunch of other stuff happening in between would indicate something else...

Comment: This gets called when the user clicks a button to retrieve data from the types.  The first button press works but when the user runs it a second time it fails.  Caching is not an option due to the information it recieves

Comment: Also as a side note this is a project which was upgraded from. Net 3.5 to 4 but this functionality didn't exist prior to the upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I had to add `<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" />` into my app.config file.  Once I did that I no longer had reflection exceptions occurring.  I still don't know why it did this but at least it's fixed.